# Regex to get values before and after 'as' keyword

Tags: javascript, regex

```
 Alias as label
```

`Alias as label,`

`[ColumnA], Alias as label, [Column B]`

`[ColumnA], [Column B], Alias as label   From XYZ`

`Alias as label, [Column A] ,[Column A] as label, [Column B], Alias as label`

`Alias as label,Alias as label From XYZ`

`Alias as label, Alias as label,  [Column A] From XYZ`

`[Column A] , Alias as label, Alias as label, [Column B]  From XYZ`

`[Column A] ,[Column B],  Alias as label, Alias as label From XYZ`

`Alias as label, Alias as label, [Column A] , [Column B], Alias as label, Alias 
as label,[Column C], [Column D], Alias as label, [Column E], Alias as label, [Column F],[Column G], Alias as label,`

`[@atiiohoi], hfghfhfffgh, P3_GRU as label`

i have words like the one above sentence i want to get the values in front and after the `as` keyword like `Alias as label and [Column A] as label` for this i'm using `(\s*(?:,\s*\S+\s*)?\S*\s*as\S*(?:\s\S+)?)` regular expression but it's not working for all cases.

The following link is the one is used to test
https://regex101.com/r/lr4GBA/1

Comment: By splitting on `as` maybe?

Comment: Maybe [`(\w+)\s+as\s+(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/zaRure/2) will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's breaking for `[Alias] as label`

Comment: Ok, try [`(\[[^\][]*]|\w+)\s+as\s+(\[[^\][]*]|\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/zaRure/3)

Comment: it's working i will run a test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex = `" as | AS | aS | As"` and use split() method

```
String mData = "[ColumnA], Alias as label, [Column B] Alias as label, [Column A] ,[Column A] as label, [Column B], Alias as label";
        String [] result = mData.split(" as | AS | aS | As");

        for(String d : result) {
            System.out.println(d);

        }
```

Output:

```
[ColumnA], Alias
label, [Column B] Alias
label, [Column A] ,[Column A]
label, [Column B], Alias
label
```